# Legit rollback in a distributed transaction: possible?

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.0

I have an EJB involved in a global transaction.
There is a part of code that, if it fails, I want to explicitly rollback although I don't want the whole transaction to fail.

As rollback is forbidden in a CMT I created a BMT and tried the following code:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
Savepoint sp= connection.setSavepoint();
try{
    //my code editing DB that could possibly fail
}catch(SomeException ex){
    connection.rollback(sp);
}
```

This way I just undo my local db modification but I also don't propagate this fail to the outside. Anyway this program fails with as:

> "Savepoint is forbidden in a distributed transaction"

Is there another approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction context is not propagated to BTM. Your bean will not be part of the global transaction either. So when your if the global transaction fails your changes could still be committed.

I'm not familiar with websphere settings but I would recheck if the connection. I expect is injected to the BTM or do you pass the connection somehow from CMT? I could try to check the container configuration if the connection is set to support jta/global transaction.
Or do you start the some `UserTransaction.begin()` before you start to work with the connection?
Still if this works it does not fix your issue.

The fit for you is use of nested transactions but they are not supported in Java EE. Just if WebShere has some provider specific way how to run them (I do not know its capability).

Then the easiest way is usage CMT `REQUIRES_NEW` but it has it's drawback in having the db change being committed even the global transaction was rolled-back.

Maybe some application desing change would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CMT by using a second EJB annotated with `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)`, where you put the code that can fail. You must than call this EJB from the other EJB.

The container creates a new transaction for the code and will rollback, if it fails.

Comment: The new transaction will also commit if it works.  Just be aware that the new transaction is independent of the first, and if something makes the first transaction roll back (for another reason) the new piece will still have committed.